# 関数の中で別の関数を呼び出す

Tags: python, python3

以下の#がうまくいかないのですがどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

```py
def sub_func1():
    print('sub_func1が呼び出されました')

def sub_func2():
    print('sub_func2が呼び出されました')

#ここにsub_func1関数とsub_func2関数を順に呼び出すtop_func関数を定義する

top_func()
```

コードは以下のようにしました。

```py
def sub_func1():
    print('sub_func1が呼び出されました')

def sub_func2():
    print('sub_func2が呼び出されました')

def top_func():
    print(sub_func1():)
    print(sub_func2():)
```

Comment: 他のかたの回答がついていますのでそれでいいですが、もしtop_func():でprintを使いたいのであれば、func1,2のprintをreturnに変えましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、関数を呼び出す時に「:」を書きません。定義するときだけ使ってください。

`print(sub_func1():)`　⇒　`print(sub_func1())`

また、関数をプリントするのではなく、呼び出したいので`print`を使いません。

`print(sub_func1())`　⇒　`sub_func1()`

最後に、プログラムの本文（関数定義の外で）top_funcを呼び出さないと、プロゴラムを実行しても何も起こりません。

以下のコードを試してください。

```
def sub_func1():
  print('sub_func1が呼び出されました')

def sub_func2():
  print('sub_func2が呼び出されました')

def top_func():
  sub_func1()
  sub_func2()

top_func()
```

回答になったでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

`print(sub_func[12]():)`が間違いです。
そこは、`sub_func[12]()`だけでいいです。

```py
def sub_func1() :
    print("sub_func1が呼び出されました")

def sub_func2() :
    print("sub_func2が呼び出されました")

def top_func() :
    sub_func1()
    sub_func2()

top_func()
```

実行結果

```
sub_func1が呼び出されました
sub_func2が呼び出されました
```

こんな感じになります